# Vue js props no data

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I cant pass data to props in VueJS.
Here is my code:

```
const projects = [{ id: 1, name: 'First', img: "https://randomwordgenerator.com/img/picture-generator/53e0d7414855ac14f1dc8460962e33791c3ad6e04e5074417d2e72d2964cc6_640.jpg" },
{ id: 2, name: 'Second', img: "https://randomwordgenerator.com/img/picture-generator/paper-1100254_640.jpg" },
{ id: 3, name: 'Third', img: "https://randomwordgenerator.com/img/picture-generator/5fe2d4414352b10ff3d8992cc12c30771037dbf85254794075287cd69145_640.jpg" },
{ id: 4, name: 'Forth', img: "https://randomwordgenerator.com/img/picture-generator/5fe1d3414256b10ff3d8992cc12c30771037dbf8525478487c2f79d5924e_640.jpg" }
] 
const Project = {
    props: ['img', 'name'],
    template: `
    <div class="container projectbox">
        <div class="textandimage"> Name: {{ projects.name }} </div>
    </div>
    `,
    
    data() {
        return {
            projects
        }
    }
}
```

img:undefined
name:undefined

Please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Projects* is a list (Array) of Objects. if you want to access an Object in the list, you need to reference its position. for example:

```
<div class="textandimage"> Name: {{ projects[0].name }} </div>
```

This will access the first Object in your list, and return the value of the key **name**

**EDIT: for-loop**

If you want to loop through the data to the template, do something like this:

```js
<div v-for="(item, index) in projects" class="container projectbox" :key="index">
  <div class="textandimage"> Name: {{ item.name }} </div>
</div>
```

Hope that makes more sense.

Comment: But what about for loop

Comment: I've updated the answer with the for-loop. If this has answered your initial question. can you mark as answered, thanks.